# The example from the "chaining computations" section of the Tokio docs does not compile: "expected struct `std::io::Error`, found ()"

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am learning [Tokio](https://tokio.rs). I read [Getting asynchronous](https://tokio.rs/docs/futures/getting_asynchronous/) from the official docs, but the source code from the *Chaining computations* section cannot be compiled under the latest Rust version (Rust 2018, v1.31):

```
extern crate tokio;
extern crate bytes;
#[macro_use]
extern crate futures;

use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;
use tokio::net::{TcpStream, tcp::ConnectFuture};
use bytes::{Bytes, Buf};
use futures::{Future, Async, Poll};
use std::io::{self, Cursor};

// HelloWorld has two states, namely waiting to connect to the socket
// and already connected to the socket
enum HelloWorld {
    Connecting(ConnectFuture),
    Connected(TcpStream, Cursor<Bytes>),
}

impl Future for HelloWorld {
    type Item = ();
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<(), io::Error> {
        use self::HelloWorld::*;

        loop {
            let socket = match *self {
                Connecting(ref mut f) => {
                    try_ready!(f.poll())
                }
                Connected(ref mut socket, ref mut data) => {
                    // Keep trying to write the buffer to the socket as long as the
                    // buffer has more bytes it available for consumption
                    while data.has_remaining() {
                        try_ready!(socket.write_buf(data));
                    }

                    return Ok(Async::Ready(()));
                }
            };

            let data = Cursor::new(Bytes::from_static(b"hello world"));
            *self = Connected(socket, data);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:1234".parse().unwrap();
    let connect_future = TcpStream::connect(&addr);
    let hello_world = HelloWorld::Connecting(connect_future);

    // Run it
    tokio::run(hello_world)
}
```

The compiler outputs error messages:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<HelloWorld as futures::Future>::Error == ()`
  --> src\main.rs:54:5
   |
54 |     tokio::run(hello_world)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::io::Error`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `std::io::Error`
              found type `()`
   = note: required by `tokio::run`
```

Is the problem caused by the version of my Rust compiler? How do I fix it?

Comment: You should file an issue for them to fix the docs.

Comment: @Shepmaster There is already an open issue, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Tokio::run`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.13/tokio/runtime/fn.run.html) has the following signature:

```
pub fn run<F>(future: F)
where
    F: Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send + 'static,
```

which means that it accepts a `Future` which accepts a `()` as `Item` and has `()` as the error type.

On the other hand, your `HelloWorld` impl has

```
type Item = ();
type Error = io::Error;
```

which means they are not compatible, you have to convert the `io::Error` to `()` somehow.

I would suggest using `map_err`

```
tokio::run(hello_world.map_err(|e| Err(e).unwrap()))
```

to handle the error in case something bad happens. You could of course make better error handling, but this will work.

---

Interestingly enough, I have JavaScript disabled in my browser and therefore I see the comments in the Rustdoc on the webpage:

```
fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:1234".parse().unwrap();
    let connect_future = TcpStream::connect(&addr);
    let hello_world = HelloWorld::Connecting(connect_future);
# let hello_world = futures::future::ok::<(), ()>(());

    // Run it
    tokio::run(hello_world)
}
```

The `#` means that Rustdoc should not print that line, but should execute it while testing. <s>I think this is a mistake/oversight and there is also an [open issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/website/issues/254) and a [fix pending](https://github.com/tokio-rs/website/pull/269).</s> PR has been merged, webpage has been updated.